# Узнать размер Map в JSP

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, map

У меня есть следующий обработчик запроса, в котором я передаю Map в jsp c помощью метода `addTeamstoModelForSelecting(teamsForSelect, teams, model)`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{seriesGameName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getTeamInfoGet(@PathVariable("seriesGameName") String seriesGameName, Model model) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Games games = seriesGamesRepository.getSeriesGames(seriesGameName);
    model.addAttribute("games", games);
    ...
        ArrayList<Team> teams = seriesGamesRepository.getTeamWhenHasNotInTeamsList(seriesGameName);
        addTeamstoModelForSelecting("teamsForSelect", teams, model);
        model.addAttribute("selectingTeam", new Team());
        return "pages/seriesGames/seriesGamesNotStart";
    ...
}
```

Сам метод:

```
private void addTeamstoModelForSelecting(String tagName, ArrayList<Team> teams, Model model) {
    Map<String,String> teamsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    for(Team t : teams){
        teamsMap.put(""+t.getId(), t.getId()+": "+t.getName());
    }
    model.addAttribute(tagName, teamsMap);
}
```

Mне нужно узнать размер этого Map в jsp.

Пробовал делать так:

```
<c:if test="${teamsForSelect.size > 0}">
```

но значение `${teamsForSelect.size}` ничего не возвращает.

Как мне можно узнать размер этого Map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подключите

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
```

Размер соответственно:

```
 <c:if test="${fn:length(teamsForSelect) > 0 }">
```